# What do γ (gamma) and λ (lambda) mean in organic chemistry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, notation

From the Wikipedia entry on [Cyhalothrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyhalothrin):

> Pyrethroids such as cyhalothrin are often preferred as an active
> ingredient in agricultural insecticides because they are more
> cost-effective and longer acting than natural pyrethrins. λ-and
> γ-cyhalothrin are now used to control insects and spider mites in
> crops including cotton, cereals, potatoes and vegetables.

[image]

**Image**: γ-Cyhalothrin, λ-Cyhalothrin

[image]

**Image**: λ-cyhalothrin (racemic)

> Gamma-cyhalothrin and lambda-cyhalothrin are the active ingredients in
> the current commercial products based on cyhalothrin. Both are
> cyanohydrin esters of
> cis-3-[(Z)-2-chloro-3,3,3-trifluoropropenyl]-2,2-dimethylcyclopropanecarboxylic
> acid. All of the insecticidal activity is due to the proportion of
> absolute stereochemistry (1R) in the mixture.[7] The active isomer of
> deltamethrin,
> (1R)-cis-3-(2,2-dibromovinyl)-2,2-dimethylcyclopropanecarboxylic acid,
> has the same stereochemistry.
>
> γ-cyhalothrin (a single chiral isomer) is indeed twice as active as
> λ-cyhalothrin on a weight-for-weight basis. The latter is racemic and
> contains the (1R) and inactive (1S) isomers in equal amounts.

[image]

**Image**: Cyhalothrin and deltamethrin acids

I have tried and tried on my own to find out what lowercase gamma and lowercase delta could mean here but I can't find an answer.

Also what does "AND Enantiomer" mean? Or is it "A.N.D. Enantiomer"?

Comment: Can you please indicate which parts are quoted? You can do this by placing a right angle bracket `>` in front of the paragraph. Right now, it's rather difficult to parse your question. I don't know which parts are you talking and which parts are you telling me about the context.

Comment: Appears to be purely marketing, chemistry-unrelated in this particular case.

Comment: The greek letters usually denote on which carbon atom on a chain some functional group is located, often counting from a carboxy group. The next - alpha, the one after the next - beta, the third - gamma, the very last on a long chain - omega. I don't understand the naming here, honestly.

Comment: I don't have the full answer but I guess it might be to differentiate the stereoisomer by using Greek letters. One example I can think of is [Lindane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindane) which is normally the "gamma" isomer of hexachlorocyclohexane and is written "γ-HCH". It has 2 isomers: α-HCH and β-HCH.